# Is there a word for "Supercomponent", similar to "Subcomponent", but in the other direction?

Tags: single-word-requests

So say you have a car, which is composed of some seats, which are composed of some fabric

You could say that the Seats are a subcomponent of the Car
and the Fabric is a subcomponent of the Seat

But is there a way to describe the relationship in the other direction?

Like "The Car is a supercomponent of a Seat"

Specifically, I am trying to list "Subcomponents" as well as "Supercomponents", and want to describe the lists accurately

Here is an example of the two lists, if I'm looking at a Seat:

```
Subcomponents:
- Fabric
- Cushion
- Frame

Supercomponents:
- Car
- Desk
- Airplane
```

I'm just wondering if there is another, better word for "Supercomponents"

Comment: It's worth mentioning that "component" can be defined arbitrarily. If you assemble a bunch of components, you could say the result is an assembly. However, if you then have to combine that assembly with some other components (or assemblies), it is acting as a component of the larger assembly. Essentially, "component" or "assembly" depends on what you need to do. The assembly created by process A could be a component required by process B.

Comment: The answers posted give some insight into how you might describe such a relationship as asked by the question, but none provide a word that succinctly expresses that relationship. I would hazard to guess that there is no such word in the English language as it is used today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In manufacturing, components are combined to create an ***assembly***. You will see this word on parts diagrams and [other documentation](http://help.solidworks.com/2018/english/SolidWorks/sldworks/c_Assemblies_first_map_topic.htm) about how to construct a machine. In fact, a component is an *assembly* of its *subcomponents*. For example, most cars have what is called a "tail light assembly" which consists of a light bulb, socket, reflector, and lens. The "seat" in your list would be ordered from a supplier as a "seat assembly" to distinguish it from the "seat frame".

However, there is a conceptual problem with your question: although the tail light is part of a car, a car is a lot more than something that has a tail light. In manufacturing, you might call the car a *product* or a *machine*.

For your list, I would use ***used in*** or ***part of***

```
Seat has subcomponents:
- Fabric
- Cushion
- Frame

Seat is used in:
- Car
- Desk
- Airplane
```

Or just say *a seat is a subcomponent of a car*.

#### Edit: On further reflection, I like my second answer better:

```
Seat has subcomponents:
- Fabric
- Cushion
- Frame

Seat is a subcomponent of:
- Car
- Desk
- Airplane
```

Comment: @BoldBen Again, you are repeating my answer. [Comments are for asking for clarification or to point out problems in the post.](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) If you just want to voice your agreement, all you need to (or should do) is upvote the question.

Comment: Quite right, I shall delete my comments as irrelevant and distracting and upvote. I was working on a tablet with a limited view of the question and thought I was commenting on the question.

Answer (score -1):

Try **construction**.

A component is literally a constituent part of something ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/component)). A subcomponent is a constituent part of a component ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subcomponent)). You're right that *supercomponent* may be odd - logically, if a subcomponent helps form a component, a component helps form, well, anything built from components. So you're looking for a word that signals how something is built from components.

One word for this is a **[construction](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/construction)**:

> 2a : the process, art, or manner of constructing something ... also : **a thing constructed**

What does it mean to [construct](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/construct) something?

> 1 : to make or form **by combining or arranging parts** or elements : build

So **the car is a construction made from a seat and other components**. Similarly, your three-part breakdown would involve *subcomponents*, *components*, and *constructions*, the last denoting what components can be used to build.

[Other words to try](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/construction) include *assembly* and *assemblage*.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't answer the OP's question. If A is a subcomponent of B, B is not a *component* of A. I believe that's what the OP is asking--what is the opposite relational descriptor.

Comment: I don't follow the objection. If A is a subcomponent of B, B is a component of C, and C is a construction or assembly of B and other components. Of course B is not a component of A; I'm unaware of making that claim.